# ¿Cómo usar django_select2 con python 3?

Tags: python, bootstrap, django, python-3.x, select2

Hace unos pocos meses estuve trabajando en un proyecto con *Django 1.6.5*, *Django-Select2 4.3.1* y *Python 2.7* pero me solicitaron pasarla a `Django 1.9` y `Python 3.4` (No usaba virtualenvs, por tanto todo estaba global en el sistema (instalado con pip)).

Entonces tuve que empezar a usar un virtualenv para el nuevo proyecto y no he podido avanzar puesto que no me reconoce el paquete `Django_Select2`, he intentado instalando desde el mismo origen y desde otros pero no me ha sido posible.

Esto es parte de mi archivo `settings.py`:

```
AUTO_RENDER_SELECT2_STATICS = False
SELECT2_BOOTSTRAP = True
SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',  # obligatoria
    ...

    'django_select2',
    ...
]
TENANT_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',  # obligatoria
    ...

    'django_select2',
    ...
]
```

Y tengo algunos formularios que tienen esta parte en el encabezado:

```
from django_select2 import Select2MultipleWidget, Select2Widget
```

Esto sería parte de el archivo `forms.py`:

```
class ActividadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActividadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        todos = Persona.objects.all()
        ...

    class Meta:
        model = Actividad
        exclude = ('programador', 'estado_ejecucion', 'estado_revision')
        widgets = {
            'ejecutor': Select2Widget(),
            'revisor': Select2Widget(),
            ...
            'beneficiarios_contratistas': Select2MultipleWidget(),
            ...
        }
```

Si escribo en la terminal `python manage.py check` ésto es lo que me sale:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
  self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/check.py", line 51, in handle
  include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
  include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
  new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
  return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
  for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
  patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
  return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/proyectos/ripso_py3d19/ripso_v2/ripso_v2/urls.py", line 39, in <module>
  url(r'^agenda/', include('agenda.urls')),
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
  urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/proyectos/ripso_py3d19/ripso_v2/agenda/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
  from agenda import views
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/proyectos/ripso_py3d19/ripso_v2/agenda/views.py", line 9, in <module>
  from agenda.forms import *
File "/home/carolina/Documentos/djcode/python3_virtual/proyectos/ripso_py3d19/ripso_v2/agenda/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
  from django_select2 import Select2MultipleWidget, Select2Widget
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'Select2MultipleWidget'

[image: Imagen Guia]

Podrían por favor ayudarme a solucionar este problema? (o indicarme otra forma de usar otro `select2` si es el caso) cualquier información no expuesta aquí me la solicitan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás utilizando la última versión de [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) debes cambiar el import en tus formularios a lo siguiente:

```
from django_select2.forms import Select2MultipleWidget, Select2Widget
```

Espero que sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Mi consejo es que intentes actualizar a la versión más reciente (si estás usando pip, puedes utilizar el comando `pip install --upgrade django_select2`. Es normal que los archivos cambien entre versiones.

Comment: Hola, me sirvió de mucho pude ver los archivos del django_select2 global de mi sistema y la del virtualenv y sí son distintos.
Pero tengo otra pregunta:
En la versión más nueva del django-select2 están los sgtes archivos.py:
cache.py,  conf.py,  forms.py,  \__init__.py,  models.py,  urls.py,  views.py

Mientras que los que tengo globales son:
dbclient.py,  fields.py,  \__init__.py, media.py, models.py, urls.py, util.py, views.py, widgets.py y otras de memcache

yo necesito usar el `AutoModelSelect2Field` q estaba antiguamente en el fields.py  y obviamente ya no hace parte del nuevo select2

Comment: Tienes razón, no aparece el AutoModelSelect2Field, lo han quitado, aunque creo que podrías lograr el efecto con este [widget](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/blob/master/django_select2/forms.py#L122), aunque sospecho va a requerir mucho más código.